# Can't delete folder in windows 10 - no error messages

Tags: windows-10

I have a folder in my `c:\Users\Username\Downloads\` folder that I can't delete. When I try, I don't get any error messages or popups, I just confirm 'Yes' that I want to delete it, that box goes away and it just stays there.

Tried several reboots, and have also tried deleting it from an administrator command prompt using `del foldername` and also tried `del /f foldername`.

Again, no error messages, just nothing happens. Can anyone help?

Comment: What's the name? Did you make the folder?

Comment: It's called 'npt' and yes I did make it.

Comment: By the way, `del` is for deleting files. Try `rmdir /s /q foldername`

Comment: Maybe use procmon and see if something has it in use and it's locking?! Also, did you try the restart incase the issue is a refresh issue (doubtful)

Comment: Thank you @Jonno that worked perfectly! If you put that as an answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why the GUI method isn't working, but the command line method to remove directories is

`rmdir directoryname`

You can also add the switches `/q` to suppress any confirmation prompts, and `/s` to remove any subdirectories and files.